# C++ Builder 10.4.2

Tags: c++, resolution, builder

I have just downloaded and installed the version free `10.4.2`.
Loaded a project from 10 (Seattle) and opened in `10.4.2` environment.
Everything is fine except the resolution of the main form: instead of `1024 x 768` it appears `320x240`.

I checked all the possible options but I didn't find where I can find the issue.
Obviously, the Width and the Height property are set `1024 and 768`.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi @Luc Perli, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please elaborate more on your question and the possible solutions you tried.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @PrabhatMishra. This project on the old environment was working fine and when I built it and then run, the main form of the application was 1024x768. Instead, compiling the same project on 10.4.2, when I run it, the main form of the application is 320x240. I don't understand why, I didn't change anything, just built on two different environment.